# Is it possible to declare a port as unknown sized 2d matrix in VHDL?

Tags: multidimensional-array, vhdl

I need to process input ports without knowing their sizes. Here is my code below. Because I am beginner at vhdl, I am confused about this language.
I am trying to compose the code on an online playground with Aldec Riviera Pro 2020.04 simulator.

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.numeric_std.all;

PACKAGE vsd is
TYPE array_2d is array(natural<>,natural<>) of INTEGER;
END PACKAGE;

library IEEE;
use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;
use IEEE.numeric_std.all;
use work.vsd.all;

entity my_conv is
port(
    in_signal : in array_2d;
    conv_signal : in array_2d;
    result : out array_2d
);
end my_conv;
architecture arc of my_conv is
function conv_fn (conv_m, conv_n,indis_m, indis_n : natural) return INTEGER is
variable sum : INTEGER := 0;
begin
    for i in conv_m-1 downto 0 loop 
        for j in conv_n-1 downto 0 loop
            sum := sum + in_signal(i,j) * conv_signal(indis_m-i,indis_n-j);
        end loop;
    end loop;
    return sum;
end conv_fn;
VARIABLE var_conv_m, var_conv_n, var_in_m, var_in_n : INTEGER;

VARIABLE temp_result : array_2d;
BEGIN

    var_conv_m := conv_signal'length(1);
    var_conv_n := conv_signal'length / var_conv_m;
    for i in var_conv_m-1 downto 0 loop
        for j in var_conv_n-1 downto 0 loop
            temp_result(i,j) := conv_fn(var_conv_m,var_conv_n,i,j);
        end loop;
    end loop;
    result := temp_result;

END arc;
```

Comment: What happened when you tried to compile it?

Comment: Yes - this has been possible since VHDL 1993

Comment: The entity port declarations for `in_signal` and `conv_signal` is the constraints for both dimensions in the subtype indication of the ports or passing the range constraints from the actual in a port map association. mkrieger is subtly hinting you could provide a [mcve] with a specific problem. A yes/no question isn't useful to future readers when the cause isn't apparent. Instantiation or elaboration of the entity would fail without constraints. Unconstrained array types were supported in -1987. In -2008 elements of an unconstrained array type are supported in unbounded array definitions.

Comment: Yes but ... not quite like that. Use the 'range(1) and 'range(2) attributes to set the size of temp_result in its declaration, and as the loop ranges.

Comment: `array_2d` declaration missing `range` x 2. The array_2d objects appear to require compatible subtypes. They should also have a known ascending or descending order which can be assured by intermediary object assignment implying subtype conversion. -2008 features (e.g. multi-dimensional array object aliases) are not guaranteed to be widely supported. The function should be impure. There's a missing `begin`, `begin process (in_signal, conv_signal)`, `begin` before `VARIABLE var_conv_m,...` and a `end process` after the result assignment (which should be a signal assignment).  Other errors.